# Pass part of the URL to a custom filter in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a database in JSON, which contents I am displaying with a controller and ng-repeat.

It works just fine.

In the list I have items that belong to multiple categories.

I have built a custom filter to only display the stuff that is matching the criteria.

```
app.filter('whichCategory', function($location){

    return function(input) {
        var out = [];   
        var path = $location.path();
        var pos = path.lastIndexOf("/");
        var categoryName = path.slice(-pos);

        angular.forEach(input, function(items) {
            if (items.category == categoryName) {
                out.push(recipes);
            }
        })

        return out;
    }
});
```

The filter works as well with a static criteria or even with categoryName but in that case only brings up the elements from one category, regardless of the url.

Any idea where was I mistaken?

Comment: if you are using `ngRoute`/`ui.router` you could take use of `$routeParams`/`$stateParams` to take the parameter value from URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I have done some debugging, and the problem is with the pos variable implementation when telling splice which side to cut from.

I was going right to left instead of the other way around.

printf debugging helped :D.

```
var categoryName = path.slice(pos+1);
```

Because the position of the last "/" character is the 11th from the left.

I need everything after the last "/" hence the +1